# I have a 100 button, click each button to display its corresponding bomb box, With javascript and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

a button corresponding to a prompt box,each box is different shells;Although implements the desired function, but my code is too complicated, and that there is no simple way. how can I do? This is my code

```
<--html button-->
<a href="" ng-click="showRulePop(1)">button1</a>
<a href="" ng-click="showRulePop(2)">button2</a>
  ...
<a href="" ng-click="showRulePop(100)">button100</a>

<--html pop box-->
<div class="note1" style="display:none;">
    <img class="title-css" src="note1.png">   
    <p class="one">note1</p>       
</div>
...
<div class="note100" style="display:none;">
    <img class="title-css" src="note100.png">   
    <p class="one">note100</p>       
</div>

<--angular js-->
$scope.showRulePop = function(index) { 
    for(var i=1;i<=8;i++) {
        $('.note'+i).hide();          
    }
    $('.note'+index).show();
};
```

Comment: What is a bomb box?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question

Comment: Please add details to your problem and add some base code of what you're trying to do see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Downvote. The question is malformed and check [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add more details about problem like whatever you tried, code you referring etc.

Comment: @gianlucatursi  Now described that clear,sir?

Comment: @Walfrat I put up my code, now can it,sir?

Comment: @Paarth now can it ?

Comment: @AnimiVulpis Try again?

Comment: @Aron Try again,sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, don't use jQuery, unless your in the directive level of angular jQuery have nothing to do there.

First let's get rid of the links part using a simple ng-repeat :

```
<--html button-->
<div ng-repeat="button in buttons"> 
    <a href="" ng-click="showRulePop(i)">{{button.label[i]}}</a>
</div>

// JS in the controller
$scope.buttons = [{
    label:'button1'
},{label:'button2'}];
```

As you can see i declare in the javascript all your buttons and i just loop over it.

Now the "bombox" or whatever it is let's make it a simple template :

```
<div class="{{currentnote.class}}" ng-if="currentNote">
    <img class="title-css" src="{{currentNote.img}}">   
    <p class="one">{{currentNote.content}}</p>       
</div>
```

// and use ng-repeat for the eight first when there is no button selected

```
<!-- show 1 to 8 if note current note selected -->
<div ng-repeat="button in buttons1To8" ng-if="!currentNote">
     <div class="{{button.note.class}}">
        <img class="title-css" src="{{button.note.img}}">   
        <p class="one">{{button.note.content}}</p>       
    </div>
</div>
```

// JS

```
$scope.buttons = [{
    label:'button1'
    note:{class:'note1', img:'note1.png', content:'note1'//assuming no HTML or you' ll need something more
}},{label:'button2', note:{...}}, ...];

$scope.showRulePop = function(index){
    $scope.currentNote = $scope.buttons[index].note;
}

$scope.buttons1To8 = $scope.buttons.slice(0, 8);//0 to 7 in fact
```

That's all, no need of jQuery.

Comment: Pretty cool ! But I do not quite understand, I need to write to button100,such as $scope.buttons?

Comment: @Phoebe yes, i wasn't sure if your 100 buttons was "manmade" or if they're generated according to some data.